# NSRange crashing with long string

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsrange

I have an attributed string that I want to have splitted up so that I can use it in a table view. Each of those items in the table view has a title and some content. The code works fine when the string file is less than 100kb but crashes when the file is larger than that.

The attributed string looks like this:

```
###Title###
Foobar some title{
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome 0.37475 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7b7f2ea0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    \"28.3L\",\n    \"56.65L\",\n    85L,\n    \"113.35L\",\n    \"141.7L\",\n    \"170.05L\",\n    \"198.4L\",\n    \"226.75L\",\n    \"255.1L\",\n    \"283.45L\",\n    \"311.8L\",\n    \"340.15L\"\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}
{
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 1 0 0 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7b7f2ea0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    \"28.3L\",\n    \"56.65L\",\n    85L,\n    \"113.35L\",\n    \"141.7L\",\n    \"170.05L\",\n    \"198.4L\",\n    \"226.75L\",\n    \"255.1L\",\n    \"283.45L\",\n    \"311.8L\",\n    \"340.15L\"\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}###Content###
{
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome 0.37475 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7b7f2ea0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    \"28.3L\",\n    \"56.65L\",\n    85L,\n    \"113.35L\",\n    \"141.7L\",\n    \"170.05L\",\n    \"198.4L\",\n    \"226.75L\",\n    \"255.1L\",\n    \"283.45L\",\n    \"311.8L\",\n    \"340.15L\"\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}BarFoo some content{
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome 0.37475 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7b7f2ea0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    \"28.3L\",\n    \"56.65L\",\n    85L,\n    \"113.35L\",\n    \"141.7L\",\n    \"170.05L\",\n    \"198.4L\",\n    \"226.75L\",\n    \"255.1L\",\n    \"283.45L\",\n    \"311.8L\",\n    \"340.15L\"\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}
{
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0.99216 0.60392 0 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7b7f2ea0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    \"28.3L\",\n    \"56.65L\",\n    85L,\n    \"113.35L\",\n    \"141.7L\",\n    \"170.05L\",\n    \"198.4L\",\n    \"226.75L\",\n    \"255.1L\",\n    \"283.45L\",\n    \"311.8L\",\n    \"340.15L\"\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}###End###{
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome 0.37475 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7b7f2ea0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    \"28.3L\",\n    \"56.65L\",\n    85L,\n    \"113.35L\",\n    \"141.7L\",\n    \"170.05L\",\n    \"198.4L\",\n    \"226.75L\",\n    \"255.1L\",\n    \"283.45L\",\n    \"311.8L\",\n    \"340.15L\"\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

And the raw string representation looks like this:

```
###Title###
Foobar some title
###Content###
BarFoo some content
###End###
```

My code:

```
struct WatchItem {
    let attributedTitle: NSAttributedString
    let attributedContent: NSAttributedString
}

class func splitAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString) -> [WatchItem] {

    var attributedString = attributedString
    var string = attributedString.string
    var items = [WatchItem]()

    while true {
        guard let titleRange = string.range(of: "###Title###") else { break }
        guard let contentRange = string.range(of: "###Content###") else { break }
        guard let endRange = string.range(of: "###End###") else { break }

        guard contentRange.lowerBound > titleRange.upperBound,
            endRange.lowerBound > contentRange.upperBound else {
            items.append(getErrorItem())
            break
        }

        let titleNSRange = NSRange(titleRange.upperBound..<contentRange.lowerBound, in: string)
        let title = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: titleNSRange)

        let contentNSRange = NSRange(contentRange.upperBound..<endRange.lowerBound, in: string)
        let content = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: contentNSRange)

        let item = WatchItem(attributedTitle: title, attributedContent: content)
        items.append(item)

        print("-----------")
        print(title)
        print(content)
        print("-----------")

        let restNSRange = NSRange(endRange.upperBound..<string.endIndex, in: string)

        //Shorten the strings to iterate over them again
        attributedString = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: restNSRange)

        //This line crashes
        string = String(string[endRange.upperBound..<string.endIndex])
    }
    return items
}

class func getErrorItem() -> WatchItem {
    return WatchItem(attributedTitle: NSAttributedString(string: "Something went wrong with your formatting"), attributedContent: NSAttributedString(string: "Please check the syntax.\n\n ###Title###\nYour Title\n###Content###\nYour Content\n###End###"))
}
```

So the code works perfectly fine when using a fair amount of those attributed strings. But when the string gets too long I get a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` exception.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing out or what the problem is with my code?

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Set an exception breakpoint.

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry I forgot to mention where it crashes. Now you should see it.

Comment: What happens if you replace the crash line with `string = attributedString.string` ?

Comment: @OOPer Paul already identified the problem for me in a private chat. The problem is that I’m running out of memory because I’m reassigning the string after each loop. He suggested to move the ranges window instead of shortening the string. I haven’t found a solution so far because I’m fighting with the string api in Swift.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Hope you can solve your issue based on the plan.

Comment: I’ll post an answer as soon as I figure it out ;)